# How to apply recursion to this code about the number of ways to sum up to 'N'?

Tags: python, python-3.x, math

Given a list of integers, and a target integer N, I want to find the number of ways in which the integers in the list can be added to get N. Repetition is allowed.
This is the code:

```
def countWays(arr, m, N): 

    count = [0 for i in range(N + 1)] 

    # base case 
    count[0] = 1

    # Count ways for all values up  
    # to 'N' and store the result 
    # m=len(arr)
    for i in range(1, N + 1): 
        for j in range(m): 

            # if i >= arr[j] then 
            # accumulate count for value 'i' as 
            # ways to form value 'i-arr[j]' 
            if (i >= arr[j]): 
                count[i] += count[i - arr[j]] 

    # required number of ways  
    return count[N]
```

(from Geeksforgeeks)

Any idea on how to do it using recursion and memoization?

Comment: Is the function intended to print the number of ordered sequences of elements from `arr` (which has `m`elements), allowing repetitions, whose sum is `N`?

Comment: Added explanation

Comment: If you copied it from the [solutions](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/ways-sum-n-using-array-elements-repetition-allowed/) it should already be O(mN)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are trying to solve is the same as the number of ways to make a change for an amount given a list of denominations. In your case, the amount is analogous to target number N and the denominations are analogous to the list of integers. Here is the recursive code. The link is https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/coin-change-dp-7/

```
# Returns the count of ways we can sum 
# arr[0...m-1] coins to get sum N 
def count(arr, m, N ): 

    # If N is 0 then there is 1 
    # solution (do not include any coin) 
    if (N == 0): 
        return 1

    # If N is less than 0 then no 
    # solution exists 
    if (N < 0): 
        return 0; 

    # If there are no coins and N 
    # is greater than 0, then no 
    # solution exist 
    if (m <=0 and N >= 1): 
        return 0

    # count is sum of solutions (i) 
    # including arr[m-1] (ii) excluding arr[m-1] 
    return count( arr, m - 1, N ) + count( arr, m, N-arr[m-1] );
```